Why is rounded-lg and rounded-md not working with Tailwind CSS for me?
I'm using Next.js 14.2.4 and tailwindcss 3.4.1 and for some reason rounded-lg and rounded-md are not working. They provide zero border radius whatsoever. rounded-xl and rounded and all the others are working just fine. I'm using shadcn-ui as well. I have no idea what could be causing this problem. I have other apps that work just fine. I deployed my app and the problem was still there in production. I also used a different web browser and the problem was still there. Has anyone encountered this problem before?
Here is my package.json. Let me know if you want to see any other parts of my app:
{
  "name": "party-bracket",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.400.0",
    "next": "14.2.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.3.2",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.6.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


Please provide [mre] so that people have code to work on.

Your package file isn't where the problem lies. Have you inspected the document? Is there a class or custom stylesheet overriding the Tailwind class?  An HTML snippet with Tailwind via CDN would be a good path to a minimal demo.

I already answered my own question before you posted this

I just found out the problem. In my tailwind.config.ts file I have:
  borderRadius: {
    lg: "var(--radius)",
    md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
    sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
  },

And I updated my :root in globals.css to not have --radius as a variable. By either adding the variable back or removing this part of code it works fine again.

as @cole mentioned, this is happening because the tailwind config uses CSS variables that aren't defined.
an easy fix would be to define those, here is a nice default start place for all those variables, taken from next.js global.css. Add it to your index.css.


@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --primary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --primary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --secondary: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --secondary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --muted: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 46.9%;
    --accent: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --accent-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --border: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;
    --input: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;
    --ring: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --radius: 0.5rem;
    --chart-1: 12 76% 61%;
    --chart-2: 173 58% 39%;
    --chart-3: 197 37% 24%;
    --chart-4: 43 74% 66%;
    --chart-5: 27 87% 67%;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --card: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --card-foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --popover: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --popover-foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --primary: 210 40% 98%;
    --primary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --secondary: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --secondary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --muted: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --muted-foreground: 215 20.2% 65.1%;
    --accent: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --accent-foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;
    --border: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --input: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --ring: 212.7 26.8% 83.9%;
    --chart-1: 220 70% 50%;
    --chart-2: 160 60% 45%;
    --chart-3: 30 80% 55%;
    --chart-4: 280 65% 60%;
    --chart-5: 340 75% 55%;
  }
}

@layer base {
  * {
    @apply border-border;
  }
  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground;
  }
}




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
